# Is it possible to add source terms on outer boundaries only in FiPy?

Tags: differential-equations, fipy

Is it possible to solve a problem on the form

[image: steady state conservation equation]

where the source term is zero everywhere on the mesh except for at the boundaries, and how can this be represented in FiPy?

I have an equation that I have so far solved in 1D with the source term set to zero everywhere. However now I would like to add a sink term (`sink`) to the left hand side of the mesh (x=0). However, I can't get this to work exactly as I want.

As the sink is exactly at the boundary it would make sense to constrain the value at the face to be `sink`. However this still results in the all-zero solution, and I assume face values are not really supposed to be used this way. If I instead set the value in the first cell center to be `sink`, then I get a solution on the form I would expect. However now the sink is not actually *at* the boundary.

Is it possible to get the source/sink exactly at the boundary?

Here is a code sample, where the flux *N* is defined by a simple [Fickian diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion#Fick%27s_first_law):

```
  L = 20                            # thickness
  nx = 100                          # number of mesh points
  dx = L/nx                         # distance between mesh points
  mesh = Grid1D(nx = nx, dx = dx)   # 1D grid of length L

  sink = -10

  c = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, name = r'$c_i$')
  c.constrain(100, mesh.facesRight)

  diffusionCoefficient = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, value = 5, name = r'$D_i$')

  sourceTerm = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, name = r'$S_i$')
  #sourceTerm.constrain(sink, mesh.facesLeft)
  sourceTerm[0] = sink

  eq = DiffusionTerm(coeff = -diffusionCoefficient, var = c) == sourceTerm

  eq.solve()

  viewer = Matplotlib1DViewer(vars = c)
  viewer.plot()
  input('Press return to continue')
```

**Edit:** mathematical expression of the problem and boundary conditions

The PDE describing diffusion of species i is

[image: main PDE]

and the source term is defined as

[image: source term]

describing a phase change from phase i to j on the boundary where c<sub>j</sub> is the concentration of the same species in the second phase (e.g. liquid/vapor). K is a rate constant. There is assumed to be no phase change other than on the boundary where the two phases meet. In my example code I just put a constant value as I was mostly wondering how to get the source term only on the boundary, I understand how to represent this source if it was on the entire mesh I think. The concentration of the second phase is calculated separately, on another mesh, with a similar equation. This should also have the same kind of source term, with opposite sign, on its right boundary, to ensure mass conservation.

Comment: Could you provide the maths for the equation and boundary conditions that you'd like to solve? It is certainly possible to make this work with FiPY. I'm wondering if there is some sort of delta function with the boundary condition when defined in weak or strong form or whether you'd like to constrain a value or have a source.

Comment: I have updated my original post with some more math!

Comment: As written the source will have no impact as it just evaluates to zero as the domains for c_i and c_j don't overlap as I understand it. If you integrate over the domain the source has a value of 0. It needs to be defined correctly either by smoothing the interface or by using a delta function.

Comment: I see what you mean, but as my complete code requires iteration to convergence anyways I simply extract the value on the boundary from the previous iteration and use that in the next, and have checked that the source term is not zero in that case. This seems to be giving the expected type of results. So really, in that case it is still a matter of assigning a constant value to the source term?